# Как получить хеш sha256 с файла?

Tags: c++, sha256

Приветсвую, как получить хеш-сумму SHA-256 с файла в виде строки.

Comment: А не в виде строки вы его уже получили?

Comment: Нет, я его получить вообще не могу.

Comment: Значит, я был прав, когда пометил вопрос, как требующий конкретизации. Вам надо сам алгоритм? Готовый код? И то, и другое несложно найти в Интернете...

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=c%2B%2B+sha256 вот тут даже код справа уже написан